# How can I clear Kubuntu Application Launcher Cache?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I download lots of videos/images etc. and even after I delete them when I use search in Applicaiton Launcher they still appear. When I untick `Expand search to bookmarks, files and emails` they are gone but now I can't search the undeleted videos, applications etc.

How can I fix this problem?

Version info of my system are:

> Kubuntu 18.10
>
> KDE Plasma Version 5.13.5

Comment: Please mention the version of Kubuntu.

Comment: @DKBose edited and added version info

Comment: • Re. the second sentence, *When I untick Expand …*, are you really sure you can't search for *applications*? I can understand not finding videos, etc but applications still show up for me. • Re. the first sentence, if I create a text file with a unique name, I can find it in Application's search and after I delete the same file, I don't find it which is what I'd expect. This is on Kubuntu 18.0**4**. I wouldn't expect the behavior to change in 18.10. Two questions: •do you have *baloo* enabled (`balooctl status`) and • does `find . ! -user $USER -ls` give a lot of hits?

Comment: @DKBose Applications still show up after untick but not all of them. Plus I still want to remove  them instead of making them unvisible.
Baloo status gives this.
`Baloo File Indexer is running
Indexer state: Idle
Indexed 6468 / 6468 files
Current size of index is 60,03 MiB
`
and when I run `find . ! -user $USER -ls` nothing visible happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting baloo index with this :

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/baloo
```

and restarting solved my problem.